# Ignore case sensitivity and whitespace in query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using jdbc to select data from a mysql database. I am performing a search query,

```
stmt.executeQuery("SELECT (NAME) FROM tablename WHERE FULLNAME LIKE '"+"a string'"");
```

How do I perform a case and whitespace  insensitive  search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

within the query you can use the function lower() to convert the string to lower case or upper() to convert the string to UPPER CASE and trim() to remove excessive spaces at beginning and end.

Your query will look something like this

```
stmt.executeQuery("SELECT (NAME) FROM tablename WHERE LOWER(FULLNAME) LIKE TRIM(LOWER('"+"a string"'))");
```

Answer (score 1):

To get around case differences you can do

```
SELECT (NAME) FROM tablename WHERE upper(FULLNAME) LIKE upper('"+"a string'""))
```

you can also get rid of trailing whitespace by using

```
TRIM('"+"a string'"")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [UPPER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper) in mysql, and on application side, String.toUpperCase();

For example:

```
stmt.executeQuery("SELECT (NAME) FROM tablename WHERE UPPER(FULLNAME) LIKE '" + a.toUpperCase() +"'");
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace all whitespace in the string (TRIM doesn't replace whitespace in the middle), you can use REPLACE. Something like the following should work:

```
SELECT (NAME) FROM tablename
WHERE lower(replace(FULLNAME,' ','')) LIKE lower(replace(yourstring,' ',''))
```

Here's a complete example:

```
create table foo (col1 varchar(100))

insert into foo (col1) values ('The Dog is sick')

SELECT col1 FROM foo
WHERE lower(replace(col1,' ','')) LIKE lower(replace('the  doG   iss icK',' ',''))
```

This returns:

```
The Dog is sick
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (NAME) FROM tablename WHERE upper(trim(FULLNAME)) LIKE upper(trim(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not Sure But You May Try this,
SELECT user 
FROM users 
WHERE UPPER( user ) = UPPER( 'anand' );

Answer (score -1):

Incasesensitive search can be achieved by using the sql syntax `ucase(FULLNAME)` and `ucase(a.string)` you're transforming both to uppercase before comparing

Comment: While this may work, a more complete answer should also mention how to handle whitespace, character sets and collations.

Comment: I'm absolutely with you, Matt! So my answer shouldn't receive any credits, instead the others.